# call a web service from a httpmodule

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I set up a web service, and I've tried to call it from my httpmodule using a Proxy class and it will just timeout.  I did more testing and tried a WebRequest and that times out also.  If I specify the wrong url it will throw an exception with a 404 so it seems like this *should* be possible.  Calling the web service from a web browser works fine so that isn't the problem.  Any ideas?

Comment: Please show a bit of code. Responses are confused as to whether you are using a WebProxy or using a class generated by "Add Service Reference"/"Add Web Reference".

Answer (score 1):

HttpModules are no different than any other code. If you can do it from anywhere else, you can do it from a module. Since you didn't say anything about actually needing a proxy, I'm unclear why you're using a Proxy class in this case. Trying to use a Proxy when it's not necessary will likely lead to a timeout, since you're sending the request to a nonexistent network proxy.

Can you not just use a [Web Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9w023sx.aspx) or [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) to connect to the service?

Comment: There is no reason I need to use a proxy, I just thought it made things easier.  Trying both ways fails.

Doesn't the URL have to be static for a web reference to work?  The host for the web service is going to variable so I didn't think that would work.

Comment: @mach77 a web reference just auto-generates the code that connects to the service and reads the xml into strongly-typed objects. You can open up that code and change it to do whatever you want, including point to different URLs based on whatever

Answer (score 0):

are you sure there isnt a proxy server between you and the web service, .Net does a good job trying to sort this out but ive found many issues letting the framework try to sort out where the proxy is.

here is a hardcoded solution which although not best practice of any sort shows how to attach a proxy to a webclient request..

```
WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy("111.222.333.444:8080");
proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Proxy = proxy;
// do your other stuff
```

ive noticed that .Net really struggles when the port isnt 80 and when the server platform doesnt have a proxy set in internet explorer, which i would prefer to be honest, i believe the default simply looks at what is set for the local internet connection but dont quote me on that